# Changing top bar color & tab bar text color

Tags: ios, xcode4, sdk, storyboard

How can I change the color in the tab bar? I'm talking about the bar when you link an NavigationController to normal UIViewController.
 
Second question. I changed the color of the tab bar (the one on the bottom, to navigate with) to blue. But now, the default text of the tab bar -from a different tab that you are on- is hard to read. As the color of the bar is light blue and the text is dark grey. Is that changeable?

I'm currently using Storyboard too.

Image:

[image: http://puu.sh/dVJl]

Answer (score 1):

The "top bar" is called the navigation bar and you can change that via the [`tintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor) property (documentation linked for you).

The tab bar also now has it's own [`tintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/tintColor) property as of iOS 5.0 (and I've linked the documentation for that too).